# iPhone OpenGl : Finding out an objects position in 3D space

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Right imagine your at 0,1,0 or even a cube is. You then rotate 45% (glRotatef), then you move that object forward (glTranslate 0,0,10) so you move that object 10 forward (I have a camera using glLookat).

How do you then get that objects position in the 3D space (not screen position)?

Is it something to do with:

```
float modelViewMatrix[16]; 
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelViewMatrix);
```

If I could find that objects position I could use it as say a bullet and then know if it hits another object very easily (I dont use the Y axes).

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply your vertexes (`[x, y, z, 1.0]`) by your modelview (`modelViewMatrix`) matrix.